# Why can't I convert a Dataframe column to intergers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV of asset price data, and I'm attempting to import it to analyze in Python.  However, I'm not able to convert the columns to integers so I can actually use the data.

I tried eliminating NaN values, but it still had issues with the first price data point.  I tried using to_numeric, but unless I change the error handling to 'coerce,' I'm not able to run the code.

I also opened the CSV file itself in Excel, and was able to sum the columns without issue, so I don't think there's a problem with the data itself.

```
import pandas as pd

prices = pd.read_csv("btc_usd_10_19.csv")

prices[["Price"]] = prices[["Price"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

Specific error:

ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "10,874.9" at position 0', 'occurred at index Price')
```

Comment: You have characters in your `Price` column that need to be taken out before converting your column to int. Try `prices['Price'] = prices['Price'].replace(',', '')`

Comment: add `thousands=','` to `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accounting format , so we need replace the ',' with '' before we convert to numeric

```
prices["Price"] = pd.to_numeric(prices["Price"].replace({',':''}, regex=True))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you!